# ASP.NET 5 Dependency Injection - Does the [FromServices] attribute only work in a controller?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using asp.net 5 beta-8, I have something like this registered as a service:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyClass, MyClass>();
```

When I use this attribute on a property in a controller, `myClass` gets set to the instance of the `IMyClass`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [FromServices]
    public IMyClass myClass { get; set; }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //myClass is good
        return View();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to use it in a class which doesn't inherit `Controller`, it doesn't seem to set the `myClass` property to an instance of `IMyClass`:

```
public class MyService
{
    [FromServices]
    public IMyClass myClass { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething(){
      //myClass is null
    }
}
```

Is this the expected behavior?  How do I inject my dependencies in a regular class?

Comment: `[FromServices]` is no longer supported on properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is when you call `new MyService()`, the ASP.NET 5 dependency injection system is totally bypassed.

In order to have dependencies injected into `MyService`, we need to let ASP.NET create the instance for us.

If you want to use `MyService` in your controller, you can have to first register it with the services collection along with `IMyClass`.

```
services.AddTransient<IMyClass, MyClass>();
services.AddTransient<MyService>();
```

In this case, I chose to use constructor injection so I don't make the mistake of trying to instantiate `MyService` myself:

```
public class MyService
{
    public IMyClass myClass { get; set; }

    public MyService(IMyClass myClass)
    {
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //myClass is null
    }
}
```

Now you are free to inject this service into your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [FromServices]
    public MyService myService { get; set; }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // myService is not null, and it will have a IMyClass injected properly for you
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you want to learn more about the ASP.NET 5 dependency injection system, I made a video and blog post here: http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/10/15/asp-net-5-mvc6-dependency-injection-in-6-steps/

Comment: `[FromServices]` has been deprecated on properties and isn't needed in constructors any more. To inject `MyService` into `HomeController` now you need a constructor: `public HomeController(MyService myService)`

Comment: The OP is asking whether [FromServices] works on types not derived from Controller. This demonstrates how to use [FromServices] on a type that _does_ derive from Controller. So I don't see how this actually answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use constructor injection for lower level classes...

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IMyClass _myClass;

    public MyService(IMyClass myClass)
    {
        if (myClass == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("myClass");
        _myClass = myClass;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I instantiate a MyService class without passing in IMyClass?

Comment: The DI container will fulfill the constructor parameters. Controllers are instantiated and their services are instantiated with the [FromServices] attribute and then all other dependencies below that are instantiated via constructor injection. Where were you planning to instantiate MyService?

Comment: For example, in a controller I want to use MyService, should I make a IMyService and have that injected as well?

Comment: Yes, and only IMyService from the controller. If the controller doesn't need to call IMyClass directly then it doesn't need to reference it.